# Pandas creating big dataFrame and filling it in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created already the columns of my dataframe

```
id=[f'GeneID_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]
value=[f'GeneValue_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]


lst=[]
for i in range(43):
    lst.append(id[i])
    lst.append(value[i])

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df = df.T
```

Now it looks like that:

```
df
Out[158]: 
                0                   1   ...                84                   85
0  GeneID_region_0  GeneValue_region_0  ...  GeneID_region_42  GeneValue_region_42

[1 rows x 86 columns]
```

GeneID_region... are my columns, and now I want to fill the columns line by line.. But I think I haven't defined my rows as rows yet because I cant do:

```
df.GeneID_region_0
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-159-2760f7e0dd61>", line 1, in <module>
    df.GeneID_region_0

  File "/home/anja/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5179, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'GeneID_region_0'
```

Can someone help me how to do that properly?

The result should look like the following:

I have an numpy array of dimension 43x25520.
I want to have 25520 values in column 'GeneID_region0'
and than 25520 values in column 'GeneValue_region0'
and so on.. so in the end I want to have a pandas frame of dimension (25520,86)

Comment: can you show us what you want your result to be like?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(value,index=id).T` ?

Comment: @Gust I added to the question

Comment: You go from having 43 * 25520 values to 25520 * 86 values. How you double the amount of values you have is still unclear to me... you concatenate?

Comment: @Gust the ID's have the index of the values, and the Value has the value .. so I am sorting values and remembering indices after sorting and saving that

Comment: @anky_91 df=pd.DataFrame(index=lst).T worked for having my columns

Comment: I'm still confused. What is 43? Is that not the number of regions? Then it seems like there should be 25520 things of type Gene... . Perhaps I'm just not understanding it but specifying what the dimensions are, and having a sketch of the output you want would be vastly helpful.

Comment: you filled your df with strings - the column names are 0...85.   It looks like what you actually wanted to do was column names GeneID_region_0  GeneValue_region_0  etc. To make a df like this you need some data first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that what you wanted was GeneID_region_n etc for column names, and then to fill your df with data. You can do this (using 0 as fake data since you didnt specify) like this:

```
id=[f'GeneID_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]
value=[f'GeneValue_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]
lst=[]
for i in range(43):
    lst.append(id[i])
    lst.append(value[i])
df = pd.DataFrame([[0 for i in range(43+43)]],columns=lst)
```